# haproxy configuration for RESTful loadbalancing - creating resurces

Tags: rest, haproxy

I am trying to come up with a haproxy configuration 
for a cluster of rest servers where the creation of a resource 
should be sent in round-robin to the servers

`POST /somecollection`

responds with the created resource uri (eg /collection/instance01 )

but then any further use of the created resources

`GET /collection/instance01/blah
PUT /collection/instance01/foo
DELETE  /collection/instance01/`

must be sticky to the server instance that handled the POST 
(where the resource has been created).

And I would like to do that without cookies :-)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is via [cookie](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-cookie):

**Example**:

```
backend rest_backend
  ...
  cookie __sticky_rest insert indirect nocache

  server rest1 x.x.x.1:xxxx cookie 1
  server rest2 x.x.x.2:xxxx cookie 2
  ...
```